# Pyspark : Inner join two pyspark dataframes and select all columns from first dataframe and few columns from second dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have two pyspark dataframes A and B.  I want to inner join two pyspark dataframes and select all columns from first dataframe and few columns from second dataframe.

```
A_df                
id  column1 column2 column3 column4
1   A1  A2  A3  A4
2   A1  A2  A3  A4
3   A1  A2  A3  A4
4   A1  A2  A3  A4
```

```
B_df                        
id  column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
1   B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
2   B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
3   B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
4   B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6
```

```
joined_df                       
id  column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
1   A1  A2  A3  A4  B5  B6
2   A1  A2  A3  A4  B5  B6
3   A1  A2  A3  A4  B5  B6
4   A1  A2  A3  A4  B5  B6
```

I am trying below code -

```
joined_df = (A_df.alias('A_df').join(B_df.alias('B_df'),
                               on = A_df['id'] == B_df['id'],
                               how = 'inner')
                               .select('A_df.*',B_df.column5,B_df.column6))
```

But it gives a weird result where it is interchanging the values in columns. How can I achieve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: `.select('A_df.*', 'B_df.column5', 'B_df.column6'))`

Comment: It is giving the same issue. Values are intermixed between columns

Comment: if column names in both tables are the same then it become ambiguous. Rename column in one of the table and do it. It will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the problem? Everything works as expected.

```
df1 = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test1.csv")
df2 = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test2.csv")

df1.alias('a').join(df2.alias('b'), ['id'], 'inner') \
   .select('a.*', 'b.column5', 'b.column6').show()

+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id|column1|column2|column3|column4|column5|column6|
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1|     A1|     A2|     A3|     A4|     B5|     B6|
|  2|     A1|     A2|     A3|     A4|     B5|     B6|
|  3|     A1|     A2|     A3|     A4|     B5|     B6|
|  4|     A1|     A2|     A3|     A4|     B5|     B6|
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```